# .Obj Faces format DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11, .obj

When I use Maya or Rhino to export a obj file(Rhinoceros has a check box for exporting texture coordinates) the texture coordinates don't export to the .obj file.

So I've looked at the stuff .obj can store and when I make something in Maya and export it as a obj it only uses this format for faces.

f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9

Which I converted too my own format.

I'm aware that you can have a position or a position and texture coord. Instead of a position, texture coord, and normal. You can have these too. When I download other peoples models or import them and other such things to play with. I get these other versions without normal and texture cords.

f 1//1 2//1 3//1

f 1/1 2/1 3/1

f 1 2 3

How can I convert everything to the first format with position, texture coord, and a normal?

Basically when I export it on Maya it is missing a texture coordinate. It just has the double slash format.

f 1/2/3 4/5/6 7/8/9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using Blender. I imported the obj into blender and re-exported it as a obj file to include the UV coordinates. That way the whole file was in the f x/u/xn y/v/yn z/w/zn format.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAqcB.png

Comment: Could you give a longer explanation?